# The multiplication of two analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f,g$ are analytic functions in domain $D$.If $fg=0$, I want to prove either $f(z)=0$ or $g(z)=0$.

Comment: If $\phi$ is analytic on a connected open set $D$, and $\phi(z) = 0$ on **any** neighbourhood of $D$, then $\phi$ is zero on $D$.

Comment: @copper.hat I am having a tough time with the proof myself. So if we suppose that for some $a \in D$ $f(a) \neq 0$ then there's an $\epsilon$ ball so that $f$ is nonzero on this epsilon ball. Then how do we conclude $g \equiv 0$?

Comment: Assuming $D$ is an open connected set and pick $z_0 \in D$ and let $z_n = z_0 +{1 \over n}$. Let $N_f = \{ k | f(z_k) = 0 \}$ and similarly for $N_g$. At least one of the sets is infinite, suppose it is $N_f$. Then the identity theorem tells us that $f=0$ on $D$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If $f(z_0) \ne 0$ then $f(z) \ne 0$ at some neighborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: so there is an $\epsilon >0$ such that $f: B_\epsilon(z_0) \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ is nonzero, how do we conclude $g(z_0)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, let $f,g$ be not identically zero functions. Let $K$ be any compact subset of $D$. If $Z_f$ and $Z_g$ denote the set zeros of $f$ and $g$, then $K\cap Z_f$ and $K\cap Z_g$ are finite sets. Now we have, $\vert K\cap Z_{fg}\vert\leq \vert K\cap Z_f\vert+\vert K\cap Z_g\vert<\infty$. It follows that $Z_{fg}$ is discrete and so $fg$ is not identically zero.